# SWFUpload and IE10

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10, swfupload

I have a web application which use SWFUpload for uploading multi files. This works fine on most browsers :-)

Now I have check this on IE10 and it doesn't worked. I have also tried the demo on http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/simpledemo/index.php . Every time if I press the "Hello" button (the button which should open the file select dialog) nothing happens...

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Steffen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

SWFUpload works on Win8 in IE10 only in the desktop environment. It seem's that SWFUploads cannot open the multi file select dialog on the new Windows 8 multi touch GUI.

I have this also checked with the multi file upload of jquery and jquery multi file upload works also on the new Windows 8 Metro environment.

Regards,
Steffen